# How to store count of number of requests on a server in a day?

Tags: http, logging, redis, counter

I have a condition where I need to count the number of requests coming on my HTTP server, aggregated by hour and request type.
For example - 
This is the kind of output data that I want to obtain if I have 3 unique resource requests

```
Resource /a - 10 req between 10pm - 11pm, 13 req between 11pm - 12am
Resource /b - 14 req between 10pm - 11pm, 17 req between 11pm - 12am
Resource /c - 12 req between 10pm - 110m, 16 req between 11pm - 12am
```

There is no requirement for real time reporting. It can stand a delay of a couple of hours. I know I can achieve this by log parsing. But just wanted to know if there is a better way to store this kind of data. Lets say a real-time counter in Redis where the key is made using `url + hour` and dump it periodically lets say every 2 hours to some other DB.

Answer (score 2):

One way to store it in redis is using hash :-

hash key as date-time sample

hashkey :- "2016-04-27-10-11"

```
"2016-04-27-10-11" :{

    "md5-request-uri-1" : "count of request",
    "md5-request-uri-2" : "count of request"

}
```

Redis functions that you can use are :- hash incr by (HINCRBY)

```
HINCRBY 2016-04-27-10-11 md5-request-uri-1 1
```

http://redis.io/commands/HINCRBY

Now you can have an hourly cron that will parse the logs for the past hour, and will store them in redis in the above mentioned format.

To get all the resources with count you can use :- HGETALL
To get the count of a particular resource you can use :- HGET

http://redis.io/commands/hget

Answer (score 1):

Log parsing or an analytics system like Google Analytics (hosted) or Piwik (self-hosted) are your best options. Don't try to track views inside your code because if you ever add a full-page cache in front it, your code won't run every time to track the hits.

Comment: Do not consider a page. Consider a single HTTP API request. So doesn't that rule out Analytics or Piwik? Yes the request can be cached on a separate layer. In that case nothing would appear on the server. That would require an altogether different mechanism to count those cached requests

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have Servlets in your application, in a high level filter apply a logic like this

hincrby(date+action, hour, 1);

```
date -> current date
hour -> current hour
action -> the action you want to save
```

if you want action a's count for overall date, do hgetall date+action for specific hour frame you can choose that alone  from the map in your application logic. Do the sum and that's your result.

In this way only one hit per request will happen. Which will take 1ms for Redis. We have been using Redis for real time analytics in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Redis fan, but I wouldn't use Redis for something like this. I would instead use a Message Queue, like RabbitMQ, or even better Kafka. Just dump your request there and have a different process pick it from there and process it.

There is no reason for adding latency(even it is 1ms) to the request serving for calculating counters or doing anything that requires a response.